# Urn function definition

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, definition

I've been reading some articles (for example, [this](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-probability/volume-8/issue-2/A-Strong-Law-for-Some-Generalized-Urn-Processes/10.1214/aop/1176994772.full)) about urn processes and they cite urn functions, but I couldn't understand what they are. Would you have any reference or clear definition about what would be an "urn function"?

Thanks

Comment: The first paragraph of your linked paper defines "urn process", and the second defines "urn function". Is there a part of those paragraphs you are having trouble with?

Comment: It defines f as the urn function in the 2nd paragraph, but I could not get how to define it. It says f is a mapping from unit interval to itself (would it be f:[0,1] -> f like f(x) = x? I couldn't understand how can I construct a general urn function for an arbitrary urn).

Comment: @VJT isn't it just an arbitrary continuous function $f : [0,1] \mapsto [0,1]$?